# Default description of return value in Doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I'm pimping my C++ library and using Doxygen to write a nice documentation. Let's say I declared type:

```
typedef enum {
    NO_ERROR,                ///< Everything fine.
    SOME_REALLY_BAD_ERROR,   ///< Something went wrong.
    VERY_INFREQUENT_ERROR    ///< Used only in some cases.
} ReturnType;
```

and use it as return values to flag possible errors in functions. Now I define a function:

```
/** Very important description
 *
 * @return NO_ERROR on proper exit, SOME_REALLY_BAD_ERROR otherwise.
 */
ReturnType ImportantFunction();
```

So with every function definition I have to paste the same description of the default return value (but sometimes I will return `VERY_INFREQUENT_ERROR` and write different description). So my question is:

**Is there a way in Doxygen to create default description of return value, or should I just create description for infrequent cases?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't create default description. What you can do is to use [\copydoc](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdcopydoc) to at least write your text only once:

```
/**
 * \class common_ReturnType
 *
 * NO_ERROR on proper exit, SOME_REALLY_BAD_ERROR otherwise.
 */

/** Very important description
 *
 * @return \copydoc common_ReturnType
 */
ReturnType ImportantFunction();

/** Very important description with very infrequent result
 *
 * @return \copydoc common_ReturnType In very infrequent cases, VERY_INFREQUENT_ERROR.
 */
ReturnType ImportantFunctionWithInfrequentResult();
```

This will generate a dummy entry in your documentation for `common_ReturnType`. You can exclude it from the output using `EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS = common_*` in you configuration file.

Comment: A few days ago I pushed. in my opinion, a possible solution for this type of problems to github "Introducing commands includedoc and snippetdoc" pull request 503. Whit the \snippetdoc this should be possible,

Comment: I guess that it will be sufficient, since I can then create a good documentation for `ReturnType`.

Answer (score 1):

You could define an alias command with exact that return documentation:

```
ALIASES += "return_noerr=@return NO_ERROR on proper exit, SOME_REALLY_BAD_ERROR otherwise."
```

Then you can use that shortcut:

```
/**
 * @return_noerr
 */
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm afraid it will mean modifying common configuration file every time I want to modify the type documentation. Since it can happen every change in the type itself I would prefer code based solution.